# How to display results in sheet2 that reference sheet1 without inserting blank lines in sheet 2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with a worksheet named "MAIN".  MAIN contains name (col A) email (col B) and cols C through F which contain codes identifying particular interests.  Interests are "NC" for Nordic center (Col c), "TM" for trail maintenance (col d), SS for ski swap (col e) etc.  So a person may be interested in helping with `NC` and `SS`.  If so, the line with that person's name and email would have `NC` in col C and `SS` in col E.

I have worksheets (in the same workbook) named `NC`, `TM`, `SS` etc.  These individual worksheets would list the name and emails of all individuals that have those codes in the MAIN worksheet. I want these worksheets to just list the names and emails of people interested in that particular area.

In the `NC` worksheet, I have a formula in col A that looks like this:

```
=if(MAIN!C:C="NC",MAIN!A:A,"")
```

The formula is active for the entire col A.  This formula will list the names of all people in the worksheet `NC` that have `NC` coded in col C in MAIN.  However, if a person does not have `NC` listed, I get a blank line in worksheet `NC`.  I DON'T WANT THAT BLANK LINE.

For example if the first and third name listed in MAIN have `NC` in col C, the `NC` worksheet looks like:

```
name 1

name 3
```

I want `NC` to look like:

```
name1
name3
```

How do I do this?

Comment: if you don't want a blank line, why do you have that as the ELSE condition in your formula?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/947848-lookup-a-value-and-return-multiple-results.html#post3367753

Comment: Why don't use pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

In sheet `NC` A1 please try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN!A$1:A$99, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(MAIN!C$1:C$99),"",ROW(MAIN!C$1:C$99)-MIN(ROW(MAIN!C$1:C$99))+1), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

It is an array formula so for entry requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. I have restricted the range here to 99 rows from sheet `MAIN` because array formulae can adversely impact speed when applied to large ranges and it seems you may want a version of this formula at least three more times. However, if you do have more than 98 names to consider adjust the `99` in the formula accordingly.

Repeat for each of the other three columns in MAIN adjusting the references to suit. For example for sheet `TM` change the 'C' column references to 'D's.